# Como usar um repositório como Package?

Tags: react, git, npm, packages

Iniciei um projeto com o create-react-library e fiz diversos componentes customizáveis com TS. Uma especie de Material UI.
Porem este projeto não pode ser de acesso publico.
Eu anteriormente queria postar no npm, pensei que teria algum jeito de pedir uma senha para instalar o pacote, porem o NPM cobra para isso, tanto para postar quanto para ter acesso.

Queria saber como eu posso baixar esse projeto de um repositório com senha (bit bucket) e usar como um pacote importando as coisas dele.

Vi que tem que especificar a dist e configurar o package.json com "name", " repository (type e url)", configuar script prepare etc. Mas não sei ao certo oque fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Para deixa seu repositório particular o GitHub tem essa opção, que você escolher deixa publico ou particular e pode adicionar quantas pessoas que pode vê e participar da criação do projeto .
O NPM é um gerenciador de pacotes do javascript e o package.json é gerado automaticamente para qualquer operação em que o npm modifique a árvore node modules ou o package.

aqui vai um link de como funciona o npm e package.json
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-node-js-modules-with-npm-and-package-json-pt

sobre o react ele foi feito com proposito para componentização, podendo importa e reutilizar em qualquer parte do projeto .

https://pt-br.reactjs.org/
Na documentação você vai poder vê varias maneiras de trabalhar com react